# Why is parseInt() not working?

Tags: javascript

I am building a calculator with JavaScript, I am just about finished but I have a single logic error.

I am trying to convert a string to a number so I can make a calculation.
 For example, I want `var value = "10";` to be converted to an integer.

I have attempted `parseInt(value1);` but for some reason this does not work - and when I got to make the calcuation it merely joins the string.

Here was my attempt (a **much** simpler version):

```
value1 = "10";
value2 = "5";

parseInt(value1);
parseInt(value2);

var calculatedAnswer = value1 + value2;
```

The above resulted with: 105
Why did it join the strings instead of converting and adding them together?

EDIT: ...and how do I solve this?

EDIT:[The Completed Calculator - thanks to your answers! :D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGGzB.png)

Comment: `parseInt` returns a new value. It can’t modify your variable.

Comment: "can't modify you variables" -? I thought that was the whole point of parseInt(), so it converts/modifies the data type. :0

Comment: just add this 
  value1 = parseInt(value1);
   value2 = parseInt(value2);

Comment: The point of `parseInt` is to take a string and *return* an integer, like how in `x - y`, `-` is an operator that takes two numbers and *produces* a number without changing the input. It’s a normal function. (No function can change a variable’s value in JavaScript – the language doesn’t have pass-by-reference at all.)

Comment: @demonhunter24 The term `parse` makes no implication about the output method, but to clarify, JavaScript does not have reference parameters like in other languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to store the parseInt value somewhere and use it. Like

```
value1 = "10";
value2 = "5";

var parsed1 = parseInt(value1);
var parsed2 = parseInt(value2);

var calculatedAnswer = parsed1 + parsed2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not assigning parsed value to value1 and value2, so parseInt(value1) wont change. You can use the below way or change parseInt(value1) to value1 = parseInt(value1) same to value 2 also;

You can also change string to number by adding `+` in the front of string

```js
value1 = "10";
value2 = "5";

var calculatedAnswer = parseInt(value1) + parseInt(value2);
console.log(calculatedAnswer)

console.log((+value1) + (+value2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
value1 = "10";
value2 = "5";

var calculatedAnswer = parseInt(value1) + parseInt(value2);
alert(calculatedAnswer)
```

You need to use parseInt output

Answer (score -1):

You can assign the parsed values back to the variables:

```
var value1 = "10";
var value2 = "5";

value1 = parseInt(value1);
value2 = parseInt(value2);

var calculatedAnswer = value1 + value2;
```